# Ionic 2 - Ion input inside card loses outline

Tags: css, angular, ionic2

My html looks like the following

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      Header
    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content>
      <form (ngSubmit)='someAction()'>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked>Some Label</ion-label>
          <ion-input name="some-input" type="text" value="some-value"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

      </form>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

The input would usually have a blue bottom outline, which then becomes green when filled in.

However, when used inside a card, the outline only appears when the input is clicked and value is inputted.

Is there a way of having the outline still display even if it is placed within a card?

Comment: The inputs inside a card works like that, if you make that form outside . card will work like you expect. So maybe change what you are trying :D

Comment: have you find any solution for this it seems like not working in ios

Comment: It's just the way way Ionic works. If you need to set the outline inside a card, you will need to do it manually in the CSS

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue in ionic
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11640

However, you can fix it by adding this code to your `app.scss` until this issue is fixed by the team.

```
.card-md .item-md.item-block:not(:last-child) .item-inner {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
}

.card-md .item-md.item-block:not(.item-input):not(.item-select):not(.item-radio):not(.item-checkbox) .item-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did that

```
ion-input {
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid map-get($colors, primary);
}
```

It's simple and show all inputs with line on bottom like it was focused. It's not the result that I would like but it's better than show blank input.